# Rake and Uninitialized Constants

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rake, ruby-on-rails-3.1, jrails

I have spent hours upon days trying to resolve this.

**Rake is throwing the following error:**

```
dcarpenter$ rake

    rake aborted!
    uninitialized constant ActionView::Helpers::JavaScriptProxy
```

*I can't seem to find anyone who has had this issue on Google, this site or elsewhere. 
What steps should I take to resolve this and what do I need to know?*

rake --trace yields:

```
/Users/dcarpenter/Dropbox/workspace/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/ext/module.rb:36:in `const_missing'
/Users/dcarpenter/Dropbox/workspace/gems/jrails-0.6.0/lib/jrails.rb:231:in `<module:Helpers>'
/Users/dcarpenter/Dropbox/workspace/gems/jrails-0.6.0/lib/jrails.rb:2:in `<module:ActionView>'
/Users/dcarpenter/Dropbox/workspace/gems/jrails-0.6.0/lib/jrails.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/dcarpenter/Dropbox/workspace/gems/bundler-1.0.17/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
/Users/dcarpenter/Dropbox/workspace/gems/bundler-1.0.17/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/Users/dcarpenter/Dropbox/workspace/gems/bundler-1.0.17/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
/Users/dcarpenter/Dropbox/workspace/gems/bundler-1.0.17/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
/Users/dcarpenter/Dropbox/workspace/gems/bundler-1.0.17/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
/Users/dcarpenter/Dropbox/workspace/gems/bundler-1.0.17/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
/Users/dcarpenter/Dropbox/workspace/gems/bundler-1.0.17/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `require'
/Users/dcarpenter/Dropbox/workspace/BlueFusion/config/application.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/dcarpenter/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/Users/dcarpenter/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/Users/dcarpenter/Dropbox/workspace/BlueFusion/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/dcarpenter/Dropbox/workspace/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
/Users/dcarpenter/Dropbox/workspace/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
/Users/dcarpenter/Dropbox/workspace/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:495:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/Users/dcarpenter/Dropbox/workspace/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in load_rakefile'
/Users/dcarpenter/Dropbox/workspace/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/dcarpenter/Dropbox/workspace/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `load_rakefile'
/Users/dcarpenter/Dropbox/workspace/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:61:in `block in run'
/Users/dcarpenter/Dropbox/workspace/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/dcarpenter/Dropbox/workspace/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:59:in `run'
/Users/dcarpenter/Dropbox/workspace/gems/rake-0.9.2/bin/rake:32:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/dcarpenter/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/Users/dcarpenter/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
```

gem list yields:

```
abstract (1.0.0)
actionmailer (3.1.0.rc5, 3.0.9)
actionpack (3.1.0.rc5, 3.0.9)
activemodel (3.1.0.rc5, 3.0.9)
activerecord (3.1.0.rc5, 3.0.9)
activeresource (3.1.0.rc5, 3.0.9)
activesupport (3.1.0.rc5, 3.0.9)
addressable (2.2.6)
arel (2.1.4, 2.0.10)
barby (0.4.3)
bcrypt-ruby (2.1.4)
builder (3.0.0, 2.1.2)
bundler (1.0.17)
chunky_png (1.2.1)
compass (0.11.5)
erubis (2.7.0, 2.6.6)
faraday (0.7.4)
faraday_middleware (0.7.0)
fssm (0.2.7)
hashie (1.0.0)
hike (1.2.0)
i18n (0.6.0, 0.5.0)
jrails (0.6.0)
json (1.5.3)
jwt (0.1.3)
koala (1.1.0)
linkedin (0.3.1)
mail (2.3.0, 2.2.19)
mime-types (1.16)
multi_json (1.0.3)
multi_xml (0.2.2)
multipart-post (1.1.3)
mysql2 (0.2.11)
oauth (0.4.5)
polyglot (0.3.2)
pr_geohash (1.0.0)
rack (1.3.2, 1.2.3)
rack-cache (1.0.2)
rack-mount (0.8.2, 0.6.14)
rack-ssl (1.3.2)
rack-test (0.6.1, 0.5.7)
rails (3.1.0.rc5)
railties (3.1.0.rc5)
rake (0.9.2, 0.8.7)
rdoc (3.9.2)
sass (3.1.7)
simple_oauth (0.1.5)
sprockets (2.0.0.beta.13)
thor (0.14.6)
tilt (1.3.2)
treetop (1.4.10)
twilio-ruby (3.3.0)
twitter (1.6.1)
tzinfo (0.3.29)
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? what's your question?

Comment: I'm new to rails and was wondering where I need to start looking to resolve the error that was thrown. i.e. do you think it may be an issue with bundler or rake or...?

Comment: I know someone has mentioned this previously but I really think your best bet is going to be to ditch jRails and move to jQuery...especially since you're in 3.1...

Comment: try at least commenting out the jRails in your Gemfile and see if that changes your output?

Comment: one sec. lemme run that real quick. i am ramping on to an existing project so ditching jrails is unfortunately not an option

Comment: rake aborted!
Permission denied - /Users/dcarpenter/Dropbox/workspace/XXXX/Gemfile.lock

Comment: existing? And it uses 3.1? That's a relatively new toy...are you sure you meant to have 3.1?

Comment: @jaydel let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2447/discussion-between-drew-and-jaydel)

Answer (score 3):

Just for the sake of saying, jrails is not complatible with Rails 3 and the project is basically dead since 2009. If you are on Rails 3 you should use the [jquery-ujs](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs) gem that kind of fills in the hole jrails used to get into.

This does not mean it's just going to work, but it's the first step of you really want to move on to Rails 3.